# How does Safari (desktop and mobile) know I have a Google account, even in private mode?

Tags: safari, keychain, privacy, accounts, google

While browsing in Safari (Private Mode as well as non-private), I recently saw multiple times some new overlay/modal that offers me to quickly create an account with that respective page using the "login via Google" feature.

I have never seen that before I actually had added my Google account to the account list in iCloud recently, and the modal is always localized (French websites ask in French, German ones in German etc.) and differently styled – so obviously Safari somehow shares with any website that I have a Google account.

I didn't find any information on how this sharing works and how I could turn it off. It's quite unsettling that information is shared even in private mode…

Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: Good quest. I was wondering this too.

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately, Safari is not sharing your data or the fact you’ve got a Google account.

This is a [Google API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) that webmasters/designers use so they can offer a secure and convenient authorization method to visitors to their site.    [Facebook (Meta)](https://developers.facebook.com/products/facebook-login/), and [Twitter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/guides/log-in-with-twitter) also offer this service. Google is just bold and very blatant about presenting the sign in when you load the page.

Even Stack Exchange utilizes both the Google and Facebook login APIs:

[image: Stack Exchange Login Page]

It’s safe to ignore and not utilize it (I don’t, personally) because it just gives Google another analytic point for analysis into creating a user profile on you.  As far as stopping it, you could try blocking Google Analytics with an ad blocker or firewall rule, but you risk breaking a lot of web page functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration, I agree with your precautions. But I just tried out to log out in the iOS Google app and delete it, and all of a sudden the modals stop disappearing (both on Google itself as on the other websites). There seems to be some system-wide information that either is shared with websites (would be really bad) or the modal is somehow injected (which also seems unlikely)…